# getting 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80] error when trying to install/apt update on WSL ubuntu18.04 OS

Tags: sublimetext3, ubuntu-18.04, sublimetext, windows-subsystem-for-linux

followed below link to install sublime-text on WSL ubuntu18.04 image,
https://tecadmin.net/install-sublime-text-editor-on-ubuntu/

but getting error on apt update:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Err:2 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'download.sublimetext.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

new to WSL, help will be appreciated in this regard.
and also any other open source tool which can help in counting and restricting the git commit message to 72 char.

Comment: While likely not related to your error, you should realize (since you mention that you are new to WSL) that Sublime is a GUI application.  WSL does not support have X server support out-of-the-box, and you'll need to install a separate X server application on Windows in order to display GUI's from WSL.  You'll also need to configure WSL to forward the display commands from WSL to the X server.